# Rails Partial: Undefined Local Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, local-variables, partials

I use rails infrequently, so pardon if this is obvious. I've looked at the other questions, am working from [Ruby On Rail Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), and it looks like I'm doing this correctly, but I still can't get my local variables to work.

**todays/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Tasks:</strong>  
  <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step_today", 
        collection: @today_lines %>
</p>
```

**next_steps/_next_step_today.html.erb**

```
  <p>
    <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step",
            locals: {next_step: today_line.next_step} %>
    <%= link_to 'x', today_line, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>
```

**next_steps/_next_step.html.erb**

```
<span class="<%= next_step.complete ? "completed_next_step" : ""%> next_step_span_<%= next_step.id%>">
<%= form_for(next_step, 
      :remote => true, 
      :html => {:'data-type' => 'json', 
                :multipart => true, 
                :id => "edit_next_step_#{next_step.id}_#{rand()}"}
      )  do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :id, :value => next_step.id) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :note_id, :value => next_step.note_id) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :content, :value => next_step.content) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :due_date, :value => next_step.due_date) %>
    <%= f.check_box( :complete, :class => "next_step_complete_button" ) %>
    <%= next_step.content %>
<% end %>
</span>
```

I know that the last partial `_next_step.html.erb` was working before I starting trying to add partials for extra flexibility. Now I can't seem to get the locals passed in correctly.

My previous working code was

**todays/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
<strong>Tasks:</strong> 

<% @today_lines.each do |today_line| %>
  <p><%= render today_line.next_step %></p>
<% end %>
</p>
```

**Error message**

NameError in Todays#show

Showing /.../app/views/next_steps/_next_step_today.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method `today_line' for #<#:0x007f930adbd860>
Extracted source (around line #3):

```
<p>
  <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step",
          locals: {next_step: today_line.next_step} %>
  <%= link_to 'x', today_line, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: FINAL WORKING CODE**

**todays/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Tasks:</strong>
  <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step_today", 
    collection: @today_lines %>
</p>
```

**_next_step_today.html.erb**

```
  <p>
    <%= render "next_steps/next_step",
        next_step: next_step_today.next_step %>
    <%= link_to 'x', next_step_today, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>
```

`collection:` does require that you use the partial file name for the local var.

I also found in my searching that if you don't use `partial:` you can also omit `locals:` and just use the variable name instead, which is cleaner. This change is shown in `_next_step_today.html.erb`. I wish I could also name the collection variable, instead of using the partial file name, or instead of using an each, but this is close enough, and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the variable within the partial is derived from the name of the partial itself, not from the name of the collection.

Your _next_step_today.html.erb should then be the following:

```
<p>
  <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step",
        locals: {next_step: next_step_today.next_step} %>
  <%= link_to 'x', next_step_today, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Edit: if you want to stick to the @collection convention, that is

Answer (score 1):

Show needs to specify the key name that the partial will use. So:

```
<%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step_today", 
    today_lines: @today_lines %>
```

Fix the spelling in next_step_today partial as well:

```
  <%= render partial: "next_steps/next_step",
      locals: {next_step: today_lines.next_step} %>
```